# Execute ng inside docker container

Tags: angularjs, linux, docker, jenkins

I was initially getting error inside `jenkins` container

```
ng:command not found
```

To resolve the same issue,i created link to `ng` file inside `Dockerfile` in following way

```
RUN echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n/opt/jenkins_home/jobs/ab-job/workspace/default/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng' > /usr/bin/ng && chmod +x /usr/bin/ng
```

Now whenever i execute any `ng` command inside container,it prints all commands which we get while `ng --help`:

```
ng build <options...>
  Builds your app and places it into the output path (dist/ by default).
  aliases: b
  --target (String) (Default: development) Defines the build target.
    aliases: -t <value>, -dev (--target=development), -prod (--target=production), --target <value>
  --environment (String) Defines the build environment.
    aliases: -e <value>, --environment <value>
  --output-path (Path) Path where output will be placed.
    aliases: -op <value>, --outputPath <value>
  --aot (Boolean) Build using Ahead of Time compilation.
    aliases: -aot
  --sourcemaps (Boolean) Output sourcemaps.
    aliases: -sm, --sourcemap, --sourcemaps
  --vendor-chunk (Boolean) Use a separate bundle containing only vendor libraries.
    aliases: -vc, --vendorChunk
  --common-chunk (Boolean) (Default: true) Use a separate bundle containing code used across multiple bundles.
    aliases: -cc, --commonChunk
  --base-href (String) Base url for the application being built.
    aliases: -bh <value>, --baseHref <value>
  --deploy-url (String) URL where files will be deployed.
    aliases: -d <value>, --deployUrl <value>
  --verbose (Boolean) (Default: false) Adds more details to output logging.
    aliases: -v, --verbose
  --progress (Boolean) (Default: false) Log progress to the console while building.
    aliases: -pr, --progress
  --i18n-file (String) Localization file to use for i18n.
    aliases: --i18nFile <value>
  --i18n-format (String) Format of the localization file specified with --i18n-file.
    aliases: --i18nFormat <value>
  --locale (String) Locale to use for i18n.
    aliases: --locale <value>
  --missing-translation (String) How to handle missing translations for i18n.
    aliases: --missingTranslation <value>
  --extract-css (Boolean) Extract css from global styles onto css files instead of js ones.
    aliases: -ec, --extractCss
```

Is it really getting executed?

Comment: can you share your full `Dockerfile` here ? so that I get some clue what actual you are doing ?

Comment: @chintanthakar,its quite difficult,but i can tell you that it is not installing angular-cli globally instead it is locally,so linking it in following way

Comment: Have you tried this `npm install -g @angular/cli` and than `ln -s /opt/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng /bin/` ? This steps you have to write in `Dockerfile` or `entry.sh` file before starting application

Comment: @chintanthakar it gives me error of python.

Comment: what is written `FROM` in your `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: `FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine` ,it is installing maven,jenkins and nodejs in dockerfile explicitly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174341/discussion-between-chintan-thakar-and-utkarsh-saraf).